# What kinds of items can I use a Reset Stone with?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

What kinds of items can I use with a Reset Stone in Alchemy?  Can the stones be used to de-volve any kind of item, or only special ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reset Stones are only used to reset a failed Alchemiracle attempt.

Alchemiracles are special patterns involving the rare armor from Grotto end-bosses, orbs from the Legacy Bosses, and Agates of Evolution. They follow a pattern of Level 1 Item -> Level 2 Item -> Attempted Alchemiracle. Each Alchemiracle has a chance of success - the average is 20% - and a failed Alchemiracle gives you a "level 3 item", one that's not quite as good as the Alchemiracle result (a "level 4 item"), but still better than your level 2 one.

Reset stones can be used on this Level 3 result to reset it back to its level 1 state in order to attempt to succeed on the Alchemiracle again.

For example:

- You obtain a pair of Sensible Sandals from Elusid.
- You alchemise these Sandals along with a Blue Orb from Nimzo and an Agate of Evolution. This yields a pair of Sagacious Sandals.
- You take your Sagacious Sandals and alchemise them with three more Blue Orbs and three more Agates. The Krak Pot will inform you that this is an attempted Alchemiracle, and ask you if you want to risk it. The game will be saved **BEFORE AND AFTER** your attempt, so you cannot save-scum this.
- Depending on your luck, you will receive either Sentient Sandals (the successful Alchemiracle - level 4/ultimate sandals) or Sapient Sandals (a failed Alchemiracle - level 3 sandals)
- If you failed to obtain the Sentient Sandals, you can alchemise the Sapient Sandals and a Reset Stone together to go back to your Sensible Sandals.

Bear in mind that if you are going for 100% Alchenomicon completion, you will have to perform both the failed Alchemiracle (Sapient Sandals), the successful Alchemiracle (Sentient Sandals), **AND** the reversion pattern (Sensible Sandals).

Comment: When you use a Reset Stone with a failed Alchemiracle attempt, do you get items other than the armor/weapon back?  (Such as Orbs?)

Comment: You do not. You only receive the weapon or armor, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

A full list of alchemiracles can be found at:

http://dragonquest.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemiracles

When these items are alchemised with a reset stone, they return to their lesser forms.
A full list of legendary equipment can be found at:

http://dragonquest.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_legendary_equipment_in_Dragon_Quest_IX